# verify email is already used or not angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I start with angularJS and I want to check if the email entered in the form already exists or not . for that, I will use RESTto communicate withe back_end.My problem is  : how to check email before sending the form with a directive and display an error message if the email is already used.

```
<form name="registrationForm">

<div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-group"
           ng-model="registration.user.email"
           ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,8})$/"
           required compare-to="registration.user.email"            
            />
```

the model

```
demoApp.directive('existTo', [function () {
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
        otherModelValue: "=existTo"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$validators.existTo = function(modelValue) {
            return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
        };

        scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
            ngModel.$validate();
        });
    }
}; }]);
```

back_end checkmail: the controller

```
demoApp.controller('signupCtrl',function($scope,$http) {
$scope.verficationEmail = function(mail) {

    $scope.test = mail;
    var urll="";
    var test="";

    $scope.urll="http://localhost:8080/app/personne/verifmail?msg=";
    $scope.aplrest=$scope.urll+$scope.test;
    var ch3=$scope.aplrest;

$http.post(ch3).
        success(function(respons) {
            $scope.data = respons;
            $scope.valid = respons.valid;

            if ( $scope.valid == "false") {
                $scope.msgalert="mail used";
            }
        })
};});
```

thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will most likely want to put the verficiation function in a service and inject it wherever it's needed:

```
demoApp.factory('verifyEmail', function() {
    return function(mail) {
        var test=mail;

        var urll="http://localhost:8080/app/personne/verifmail?msg=";
        var aplrest=urll+test;
        var ch3=aplrest;

        return $http.post(ch3)
    };
});
```

Then...

In your directive:

```
demoApp.directive('existTo', ["$q","verifyEmail",function ($q, verifyEmail) {
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
        // This is probably not needed as ngModel's 
        // validators will pass the current value anyway
        otherModelValue: "=existTo"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        // Note the change to $asyncValidators here            <-------------
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.existTo = function(modelValue) {
            var deferred = $q.defer()
            verifyEmail(modelValue).then(function(respons){
                deferred.resolve(respons.valid);
            });
            return deferred.promise
        };

        scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
            ngModel.$validate();
        });
    }
}; }]);
```

In your controller:

```
demoApp.controller('signupCtrl',function($scope,$http,verifyEmail) {
    $scope.verficationEmail = function (mail) {
        verifyEmail(mail).success(function(respons) {
            $scope.data = respons;
            $scope.valid = respons.valid;

            if ( $scope.valid == "false") {
                $scope.msgalert="mail used";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also, in your html you **dont** seem to be actually using the directive `exist-to`, I'm guessing that's what `compare-to` should have been. But, in any case, it might look like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-group"
       ng-model="registration.user.email"
       ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,8})$/"
       required exist-to            
        />
```

Note that there's no need to pass the model value to the directive

Hope that helps.

Comment: and to print an error message is that true                                                              <span ng-show="registrationForm.email.$error.existTo">mail already exist.</span>                                                                                                            thank's for your help

Comment: i use your solution and i have this probleme deffered is not defined please can you help me ?

Comment: Its a simple typo in the directive. the `deffered.promise` in the return statement should be `deferred.promise`. I've updated.

Comment: even after the update a  i have the same problem: deffered is not defined

Comment: Im not sure why that is... but the directive is the only place that variable name was used. perhaps you can search and replace all occurrences of `deffered` with `deferred` in your project files.

Comment: i replace deffered by deferred and i dont have the compliation error but it still don't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719091/directive-angularjs-to-check-mail-used-or-not