# directive angularjs to check mail used or not

Tags: angularjs

i want to check if email is already used or not  (communication with back-end) but the error message is not shown in the screen.

the verficiation function service :

```
demoApp.factory('verifyEmail', function($http) {
    return function(mail) {
        var test=mail;
        var urll="http://localhost:8080/app/personne/verifmail?msg=";
        var aplrest=urll+test;
        var ch3=aplrest;

        return $http.post(ch3)
    };});
```

the directive (with the help of @jsonmurphy)

```
demoApp.directive('existTo', ["$q","verifyEmail",function ($q, verifyEmail) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=existTo"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            // Note the change to $asyncValidators here            <-------------
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.existTo = function(modelValue) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                verifyEmail(modelValue).then(function(respons) {
                    // the respons can be {exist="true"} or{exist="false"} 
                   var rep=respons.exist;
                    deferred.resolve(rep);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
                ngModel.$validate();
            });
        }
    }; }]);
```

the html file:

```
<label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-group"
           ng-model="registration.user.email"
           ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,8})$/"
           required exist-To="registration.user.email"/>

    <span style="color:red" ng-show="registrationForm.email.$dirty && registrationForm.email.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="registrationForm.email.$error.required">champs email obligatoire.</span>
        <span ng-show="registrationForm.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email address.</span>
        <span ng-show="registrationForm.email.$error.existTo">mail already exist.</span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

this the solution

```
demoApp.directive('existTo', ["$q","verifyEmail",function ($q, verifyEmail) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=existTo"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            // Note the change to $asyncValidators here            <-------------
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.existTo = function(modelValue) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                // window.alert("l email a tester "+modelValue);
                verifyEmail(modelValue).success(function(respons) {
                    // the respons can be {exist="true"} or{exist="false"}
                  //  window.alert("la reponse " +respons);
                    var rep=respons.exist;
                   // window.alert("la reponse " +rep);

                    if (rep =="false") {
                        // The username is available
                        deferred.resolve();
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject();
                    }

                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
                ngModel.$validate();
            });
        }
    }; }]);
```